# How to write a MoveIt Controller Allocator

Tags: moveit, ros-noetic

I wrote my own Joint Trajectory Controller to use with MoveIt instead of the standard `velocity_controllers/JointTrajectoryController`.

The new controller is loaded and listed by the controller manager, which means that pluginlib is able to find it and load it.

When MoveIt `MoveGroup` node is launched with Gazebo & RViz and I click Plan & Execute trajectory in RViz, MoveIt then complains it can't find a controller to actuate the joints.

I debugged into Move Group node, and my custom controller is being listed as a "loaded controller", but it can't be used with MoveIt because any controller used with MoveIt needs an Allocator defined.

I found this mentioned in MoveIt 1 documentation for plug-ins:

https://moveit.ros.org/documentation/plugins/#controllerhandleallocator

> By implementing the [ControllerHandle.h](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/4ac0c7432d335f57aab6836cbcaaac3fccf4b6f9/moveit_plugins/moveit_ros_control_interface/include/moveit_ros_control_interface/ControllerHandle.h) interface it is possible to offer allocations of handlers for action based controllers. The controller handler are based on the class [MoveItControllerHandle](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_core/controller_manager/include/moveit/controller_manager/controller_manager.h). These handlers communicate with the controller in order to e.g. send trajectories.

> The interface is defined in [ControllerHandle.h](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/4ac0c7432d335f57aab6836cbcaaac3fccf4b6f9/moveit_plugins/moveit_ros_control_interface/include/moveit_ros_control_interface/ControllerHandle.h).

> An examplary implementation of this interface is the [joint_trajectory_controller_plugin.cpp](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/master/moveit_plugins/moveit_ros_control_interface/src/joint_trajectory_controller_plugin.cpp). This is also currently the only implementation available.

However, after adding the following MoveIt 1 dependencies in `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt`, the headers it's talking about are not found:

- `moveit_core`
- `moveit_ros_control_interface`

For instance, the following includes can't be found by the compiler (normally they would be in `${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}` after telling CMake about a package dependency):

```
#include <moveit/controller_manager/controller_manager.h>
#include <moveit/moveit_plugins/moveit_ros_control_interface/controller_handle_allocator.h>
#include <moveit/moveit_plugins/moveit_ros_control_interface/moveit_controller_handle.h>
#include <moveit/moveit_plugins/moveit_ros_control_interface/follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle.h>
```

These headers I am trying to include can be seen here:

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/master/moveit_plugins

What do I do next? Filed an issue in MoveIt repo here:

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/3555

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After including the `ros_control_interface` as a dependency in `package.xml` and `CMakeLists`, I decided to dump all header paths known by CMake by using this trick:

[How to Print Variable in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68139352/how-to-print-variables-in-cmake)

This revealed that bringing in `ros_control_interface` gave me access to just one MoveIt header I really needed:

```
#include <moveit_ros_control_interface/ControllerHandle.h>
```

Basically I just looked for any header paths known to CMake that contained the string "moveit_ros_control_interface", and then followed a pattern used by other headers which were included successfully to find out the `#include` did not start with `moveit/`, etc.

This was of course not documented (but don't worry, I will update the docs when I have more time).

Upon including this header, I gained access to the following namespaces and classes, which is all that was needed to implement a controller handle, and a controller handle allocator:

- `controller_interface::Controller`
- `moveit_controller_manager::MoveItControllerHandle`
- `moveit_ros_control_interface::ControllerHandleAllocator`

With this, MoveIt finally recognized my custom trajectory controller as a controller it can use. You can see my implementation here:

- [trajectoryController.h](https://github.com/01binary/str1ker/blob/master/src/include/trajectoryController.h)
- [trajectoryController.cpp](https://github.com/01binary/str1ker/blob/master/src/trajectoryController.cpp)